# Access/Modify master page's control in other pages - Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

By reading title of question you would get the idea about my question.

Suppose I'd a button or  in master page, which says log in and when user logged in successfully then it'd to change into log out button.

Is it possible ? to change master page control from other pages? and is it possible to change events of master pages (as well as other pages) pragmatically from other pages ?

If yes, then please help me out!

Thanks in advance.

P.S: if you don't understand my question then please ask me, don't report it please!

Comment: Why not just put your login button in your master page.. ?

Comment: Login button is in master page, When the user logged in then it must or it'll change into logout button.
is that possible?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. Why don't you post your code and show us what the problem is ?

Comment: Control exists on master page, Before Login
<asp:button runat="Server" text="Log in" OnClick="somefun()" />

After successful login its text changed into "logout" and onclick event must point to log out fun. I dont know how to do that. can you please help me out?

Comment: what is the code in your somefun() method ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access MasterPage's controls from ContentPage and i can provide you the details, but i think in your case you don't need this and you are in wrong way.
You have many other options like putting two login and logout buttons in master page and show or hide them depend on user authentication status.

then after login in content page, do a refresh, so the master page show the correct button.
Or as a second solution put login and logout button in a updatepanel, so you don't need even refresh.

I think change events of master pages pragmatically from other pages isn't a good way at all.
You just need to create both login and logout buttons and related events and show/hide them depend on authentication status.

**Update:**

Create login and logout buttons in master page and config related events, then in codebehind in your masterpage in `Page_Load` try this:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated == true) {
    //User is logged in
    btnLogin.Visible = false;
    btnLogout.Visible = true;
} else {
    //User is logged Out
    btnLogin.Visible = true;
    btnLogout.Visible = false;
}
```

So every time that masterpage load, depending on authentication's status of user, show the correct buttons.

Comment: Never cross my mind.
'some code
If(login.visible) Then 'successfully logged in because login button is  visible
login.visible=false
logout.visible=true

Is this true?
By the way, thank you for your help. I really appreciate your idea :D

Comment: Thanks mate. this is really helpful :)
God Bless yaa

Comment: Btw can I ask you something else ?

Comment: @SikanderHayyat: Absolutely, but if the questions are different from the topic of this question, it's better to create new questions and send me their links.